# Best way to apply css using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For applying CSS with '!important', we need to use looping currently since following code is not supported in IE8 and IE9

`$('.YourClass').css('width','100px !important');`

I come up to following solution which works in all browsers(tested on IE 8 - 11, Chrome, Firefox and Safari running on windows machines)

`$('.YourClass').each(function(){this.style.setProperty('width', '100px', 'important')});`

Advantages:

1. Avoid checking for existing property declaration.
2. No need to append your css code.
3. No need to iterate using looping.
4. Same function can be used without using '!important'. So no need to use two different functions for same purpose.
5. Doesn't overwrite existing inline style declaration like setting 'style' attribute by various ways.

Can we make this solution better?

Comment: The question is modified now...hope it will help removing non-positive votes

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to iterate over the all elements. you can simply set the css:

```
$('.YourClass').css('width','100px !important');
```

Comment: It doesn't work in all browsers...especially IE8 and IE9...that why style.setProperty comes in picture

Comment: @ParvejSolkar: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: @ParvejSolkar: i am looking into that